# How can I play as Connor?

Tags: assassins-creed-3-liberation

Well, supposedly you unlock a Connor mission (or skin, I really didn't get that) when you link AC III with Liberation. I got Connor's Tomahawk, but I don't see how to play as Connor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that this is a single story mission towards the end of the game that involves both Aveline and Connor. After you complete this mission, if you have linked you AC3 and AC3:L games you can choose to replay the mission as Connor and select Connor as an outfit from the dressing chamber.

[Source](http://www.themarriedgamers.net/2012/10/assassins-creed-iii-liberation-trailer-shows-off-controls/)

Comment: In the leaflet ( http://i.imgur.com/rLk17.jpg ) it says there is an exclusive mission. If that is the mission, it isn't particularly exclusive... and it's what it's called misleading advertising...

Comment: Btw, you actually can. When you finish the mission, as an Easter Egg you get to play with him on New Orleans. If you change persona/suit, you get back being Aveline though.

Comment: Oh Ok, I will take that info out of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Multiplayer in Liberation isn't anything like on the console versions, so no chance that he shows up there.